# Why is「ん」the only kana without a vowel?

Tags: etymology, kana

I've always wondered why「ん」is the only kana without having a vowel sound attached to it. The only thing I've ever heard is that 「ん」 is a special kana that can be the last kana in some words.

I've also heard something about a discrepancy between ん and む regarding 変体仮名. Does this factor into the reason at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Japanese only allows gemination and nasal as the coda of a syllable. The two kanas っ and ん correspond to them, and are the kanas without a vowel. Also, when a kana is followed by a glide such as in ゃ, ゅ, or ょ, it loses the vowel. For example, In きゃ, き only represents k, not ki.

In general, languages disfavor coda, and nasal is among the sounds that can easily become a coda because the mouth is closed. For example, Chinese and Korean also allow a limited variety of coda, among which are nasal sounds.

In Classic Japanese, the vowel u in mu often dropped.

> 風吹かむとす → 風吹かんとす

Answer (score 4):

I think Sawa nailed it, I just want to add a few things that I think are interesting. There is apparently controversy in the syllable-based model of Japanese prosody. This paper [Questioning the universality of the syllable : evidence from Japanese* (Labrune, 2012)](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8538016) where, just taking from the abstract:

> whereas the mora and the foot are indisputably present and active, the evidence for the syllable is inconspicuous and disputable. Building on this observation, I claim that Tokyo Japanese makes no use of the syllable. Instead, two types of mora are distinguished: regular CV moras and weak (deficient) moras. Weak moras include the moraic nasal, the first part of a geminate and the second part of a long vowel, as well as moras containing an onsetless vowel, a devoiced vowel or an epenthetic vowel.

Then taking from her paper:

> The linguistic tradition among Japanese has never had the need to refer to a unit such as the syllable in opposition to the mora in accounts of Tokyo Japanese. A number of modern Japanese phonologists belonging to the traditional mora-model school of Japanese linguistic analysis continue this tradition. Some of them (for instance [現代日本語方言辞典(Hirayama, 1992)](http://www.meijishoin.co.jp/book/b97516.html) and [現代日本語の発音分布(Sato, 2002)](http://karaimobooks.shop-pro.jp/?pid=22261336)) even operate with an explicit
> distinction between mora-based and syllable-based dialects. Dialects such
> as Aomori and Akita (North Honshu), and Kagoshima (South Kyushu),
> are held to be indisputably syllabic, while others, for instance the Osaka
> dialect and the Izu dialect (south of Tokyo) are clearly moraic, and are
> considered to be such even by some advocates of a syllabic analysis
> of Tokyo Japanese.

> It is actually Tokyo Japanese (Standard Japanese), the
> most extensively studied dialect, which poses a problem with regard to
> classification as a mora or syllable dialect, as it has been analysed both as
> only moraic and as syllabic with moras.

And I think most importantly:

> Moreover the linguistic facts that support the relevance
> of the syllable in Tokyo Japanese can always receive an alternative,
> syllable-free account, which works at least as well as the syllabic analysis.

I haven't really read into this topic, so I don't have much opinion on the matter. Just thought it would be interesting to point out.

Also, the geminate /Q/ and nasal /N/ consonants are not the only vowelless mora-long segments in Japanese. [だめっ]! has the transcription /dameQ/ where /Q/→[ʔ] the glottal stop consonant. /Q/ is a phoneme and has mora-long duration, but [ʔ] is not distinctive.

Comment: Labrune also writes extensively on this topic in The Phonology of Japanese (2012).